# Como pegar valor de uma coluna da tabela

Tags: php, html

Eu queria pegar o valor de pontos do usuário logado e colocar na minha página.
Essa é a tabela "usuarios"
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo:
"Você possui x pontos"

Abaixo página login.php

```
  <?php 
  $login = $_POST['login'];
  $entrar = $_POST['entrar'];
  $senha = md5($_POST['senha']);
  $connect = mysql_connect('xxxx','xxxxx','xxxxxxx');
  $db = mysql_select_db('xxxxxxxxx');
    if (isset($entrar)) {

      $verifica = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login' AND senha = '$senha'") or die("erro ao selecionar");
        if (mysql_num_rows($verifica)<=0){
          echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Login e/ou senha incorretos');window.location.href='login.html';</script>";
          die();
        }else{
          setcookie("login",$login);
          header("Location:index.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Coloque o código de login na pergunta para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Comment: Qual código? Da página login toda?

Comment: Você quer mostrar essa pontuação na página index.php, correto?

Comment: Isso, exatamente.

Comment: Se tu só quer obter o valor dos pontos basta reaproveitar a query que tu fez.

$fetch = mysql_fetch_object($verifica);

e posteriomente exibir o valor dos pontos $fetch->pontos;

Ou guardar numa session. Indico também que use Mysqli ou PDO como drive de conexão mysql_* não recebe mais suporte.

Comment: Como faria isso, Mauro? Sou bem leigo em PHP....

Comment: Caso alguma resposta resolva seu problema marque-a como aceita. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx7Ts.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Aproveita e faça um tour em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editei a resposta e atualizei para `MySQLi` porque a versão que você está usando `MySQL` está descontinuada

```
$connect = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "Nome_DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login' AND senha = '$senha'";
$buscar=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
$dados=mysqli_fetch_array($buscar);

$result=mysqli_num_rows($buscar);

if ($result==1) {

    $pontos = $dados["pontos"];

    setcookie("login",$login);
    header("Location:index.php?pontos=".$pontos);

}else|{

    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Login e/ou senha incorretos');window.location.href='login.html';</script>";
    die();

}
```

Na pagina index recupere via GET

```
$pontos = $_GET['pontos'];
```

dai você coloca onde quiser

> dentro do PHP

```
 echo $pontos;
```

> dentro do HTML

```
<?php echo $pontos ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Já existem thread explicando como fazer isso, não especificamente teu problema, mas como informou que é leigo na linguagem vou explicar como resposta.

Esse é o teu código (aparentemente está funcionando)

```
  <?php 
  $login = $_POST['login'];
  $entrar = $_POST['entrar'];
  $senha = md5($_POST['senha']);
  $connect = mysql_connect('xxxx','xxxxx','xxxxxxx');
  $db = mysql_select_db('xxxxxxxxx');
    if (isset($entrar)) {

      $verifica = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login' AND senha = '$senha'") or die("erro ao selecionar");
        if (mysql_num_rows($verifica)<=0){
          echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Login e/ou senha incorretos');window.location.href='login.html';</script>";
          die();
        }else{
          setcookie("login",$login);
          header("Location:index.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Nessa linha `$verifica = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login' AND senha = '$senha'") or die("erro ao selecionar");` você está selecionando tudo da tabela `usuarios` onde as credenciais estejam de acordo.

Essa query está trazendo todos os dados da tabela, desde que o os dados digitados estejam ok.

Nessa linha `if (mysql_num_rows($verifica)<=0)` você está verificando se o usuário não existe, no `else` você está salvando o login na numa sessão, a lógica é a mesma, basta no bloco do `else` adicionar `$fetch = mysql_fetch_object($verifica);` e acessar o valor de pontos `$fetch->pontos;`

no final teu código ficaria

```
  <?php 
  $login = $_POST['login'];
  $entrar = $_POST['entrar'];
  $senha = md5($_POST['senha']);
  $connect = mysql_connect('xxxx','xxxxx','xxxxxxx');
  $db = mysql_select_db('xxxxxxxxx');
    if (isset($entrar)) {

      $verifica = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login' AND senha = '$senha'") or die("erro ao selecionar");
        if (mysql_num_rows($verifica)<=0){
          echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Login e/ou senha incorretos');window.location.href='login.html';</script>";
          die();
        }else{
          setcookie("login",$login);

          $fetch = mysql_fetch_object($verifica);
          $_SESSION["pontos"] = $fetch->pontos;
          header("Location:index.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Para acessar o valor da sessão na `index.php` basta iniciar a sessão no arquivo e obter o valor.

index.php

session_start();

echo "você tem " . $_SESSION["pontos"] . " pontos";

Comment: E como colocaria na index.php tipo "Você possui x pontos"?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Não puxou a quantidade de pontos :/

Comment: Qual erro exibe? abre o teu log de erros do PHP e vê o que gera.

Normalmente isso deve funcionar, a menos que seu código inicial esteja com problemas.

Comment: Coloquei assim:
<div class="alerta"> <p> Hey, <?php echo $login_cookie; ?> .

 <?php
session_start();
echo "você tem " . $_SESSION["pontos"] . " pontos";
?>

E apareceu na index.php "Hey, teste . você tem pontos "